# Access nested prop with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux. I'm trying to access nested data within my retailer prop. I would like to be able to access the retail 'name' and validate the prop as a string with prototypes. When I try to access the 'name' within render it breaks the app. Is there a better way to do this we Redux.

```
class MyPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props;

    this.props.getRetailer(id);
  }

  render() {
    const { retailer } = this.props.retailer;
    const { name } = this.props.retailer && this.props.retailer.retailer;

    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          name={name}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  retailer: state.retailer
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getRetailer
})(MyPage);
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @WilsonLiao Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(this.props.retailer && this.props.retailer.retailer)' as it is null

Comment: You can also do `const name = this.props?.retailer?.retailer?.name` it's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `this.props.retailer && this.props.retailer.retailer;` might return null when retailer is not present and hence it will try to resolve name from null which will throw an error

You can use destructuring with fallback like

```
const { retailer } = this.props.retailer || { retailer: {} }; 
const { name } = retailer || {};
```

The above will handle both the cases of `this.props.retailer` being null or undefined as well as `this.props.retailer.retailer` being null or undefined